# PostgreSQL export result as CSV from remote server

Tags: bash, postgresql, csv, remote-server

I have read all other solutions and none adapts to my needs, I do not use Java, I do not have super user rights and I do not have API's installed in my server.

I have select rights on a remote PostgreSQL server and I want to run a query in it remotely and export its results into a .csv file in my local server.

Once I manage to establish the connection to the server I first have to define the DB, then the schema and then the table, fact that makes the following lines of code not work:

```
\copy schema.products TO '/home/localfolder/products.csv' CSV DELIMITER ','

copy (Select * From schema.products) To '/home/localfolder/products.csv' With CSV;
```

I have also tried the following bash command:

```
 psql -d DB -c "select * from schema.products;" > /home/localfolder/products.csv
```

and logging it with the following result:

> -bash: home/localfolder/products.csv: No such file or directory

I would really appreciate if someone can show a light on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried this? I do not have psql right now to test it.

```
echo “COPY (SELECT * from schema.products) TO STDOUT with CSV HEADER” | psql -o '/home/localfolder/products.csv'
```

Details:

```
-o filename   Put  all  output into file filename.  The path must be writable by the client.
echo builtin + piping (|) pass command to psql
```

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that the server is remote, however you are connecting to a localhost. Add the -h [server here] or set the ENV variable

```
export PGHOST='[server here]'
```

The database name should be the last argument, and not with -d.
And finally that command should have not failed, my guess is that that directory does not exist. Either create it or try writing to tmp.

I would ask you to try the following command:

```
psql -h [server here] -c "copy (select * from schema.products) to STDOUT csv header" DB > /tmp/products.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Aftr a while a good colleague deviced this solution which worked perfectly for my needs, hope this can help someone.

```
'ssh -l user [remote host] -p [port] \'psql -c "copy (select * from schema.table_name') to STDOUT csv header" -d DB\' > /home/localfolder/products.csv'
```

Very similar to idobr's answer.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html:

> Files named in a COPY command are read or written directly by the server, not by the client application.

So, you'll always want to use [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)'s [\copy](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) meta command.

The following should do the trick:

```
\copy (SELECT * FROM schema.products) to 'products.csv' with csv
```

If the above doesn't work, we'll need an error/warning message to work with.